# How add dig in a string by index without deleting anything

Tags: python, pandas

How adding a dig `/` in a string that looks like this:

`012019`

so it will look like this:

`01/2019`

Also add maybe day like

`01/01/2019`

The data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({ "month": ["012019","152019","222019","142019","302019","012020"]})
```

My code:

```py
df.month = df.month.apply(lambda x: '{:0>2}'.format(x.split('/')[0]))
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you just want to add a slash between 2nd and 3rd characters. then it's easy:

```
df['new'] = df.month.str.slice(0, 2) + '/' + df.month.str.slice(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC just convert to datetime and use `dt.strftime`

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'],format='%d%Y').dt.strftime('%d/%Y')
```

---

```
output:
print(df)
     month
0  01/2019
1  15/2019
2  22/2019
3  14/2019
4  30/2019
5  01/2020
```

if you want to add a month as well just add it to your string

```
month = '01' 

df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'].astype(str) + 
month,format='%d%Y%m').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

---

```
print(df)
        month
0  01/01/2019
1  01/15/2019
2  01/22/2019
3  01/14/2019
4  01/30/2019
5  01/01/2020
```